# How does resizing images via get requests work?

Tags: image, dynamic, get, resize, request

I've seen a couple of sites do the following:

example.com/test.png?w=100&h=100

So that the image is 100 x 100 pixels.

Those are used as thumbnails, then if you click on one, a part of that page will change to show that image, it's the same one, except this time the w and h requests are different:

example.com/test.png?w=500&h=500

(specifically, I'm talking about Everlane https://www.everlane.com/collections/mens-tees/products/mens-crew-black)

Can someone explain this to me? What exactly is going on when those get variables are passed?

Comment: The web server is dynamically resizing the image and writing it out as the response.

Comment: They use the service https://www.imgix.com/, but it's possible to run something like this on a private webserver as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you mentioned they are using 'Imgix' service. But without that you can implement a similar thing using MVC framework (like codeigniter) though.

Here, 'i' in the url of the webpage is the function name in the controller. Variable $file will get the next part after 'i' in the url.

Read about it [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/).

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

        public function i($file)
        {
           parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
           echo '<img src='.$file.' width='.$_GET['w'].' height='.$_GET['h'].'>';           
        }
}
```

**Also you have to enable get array in config.php

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```